# Def doesn't work

Tags: python

Not sure why this code doesn't work.

```
class convert_html(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def convert_syntax(self, html, preprocessor)
    return "this is just a " + preprocessor + " test"

  def convert_to_jade(self, html):
    return self.convert_syntax(html, "jade")

  def run(self, edit):
    with open(self.view.file_name(), "r") as f:
      html = f.read()
      html = html.convert_to_jade(html)
      print(html)
```

It says `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'convert_html'`

How do I make it work?

Comment: add the code where you're using this class

Comment: You are missing a colon at the end of `def convert_syntax(self, html, preprocessor)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to invoke the `convert_to_jade()` method using the the `self` variable, which acts as a reference to the current object of the class. Quite similar to the `this` pointer in `C++` or `java`

```
  html = self.convert_to_jade(html)
```

Python passes this instance handle implicitly as the first argument to the method when you invoke `self.something()`. And without the instance handle (i.e. `self`), you would not be able to access any instance variables.

BTW, it is not mandatory to name the first argument of instance methods as `self`, but it is a commonly used convention.

More on `self` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

The following code should work:

```
class convert_html(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def convert_syntax(self, html, preprocessor):
    return "this is just a " + preprocessor + " test"

  def convert_to_jade(self, html):
    return self.convert_syntax(html, "jade")

  def run(self, edit):
    with open(self.view.file_name(), "r") as f:
      html = f.read()
      html = self.convert_to_jade(html)
      print(html)
```

Comment: I've also tried `html = convert_to_jade(html)` and `def convert_to_jade(html):` but it didn't work. Can you explain please, why?

Comment: @Steve - have updated the answer with more info about why you need to use `self` and also a link to another SO question, which should give you all the details about `self`.